# How do I not escape unicode in python2?

Tags: python, unicode

Is there a way to reproduce py3's **not** escaping Unicode in repr() in Python 2?

```
$ python3
>>> s="…\n…"
>>> print(repr(s))
'…\n…'
```

but

```
$ python2
>>> s=u"…\n…"
>>> print repr(s)
u'\u2026\n\u2026'
```

I want

```
u'…\n…'
```

The solution I've managed to come up with is

```
#!/usr/bin/python

import re
_uregex=re.compile("\\\\([^uU])")

def _ureplace(x):
    x = x.group(1)
    if x == "\\":
        return "\\\\\\\\" # Eight of them. Required.
    return "\\\\"+x
def urepr(x):
    return _uregex.sub(_ureplace,repr(x)).decode("unicode-escape")

s = u"\u2026\n\u2026"
print(urepr(s))
```

but I wonder whether there's a better way to do this – escaping everything, just to unescape everything back, seems rather wasteful. And slow (I need this for quickly writing a lot of large-objects' repr to a logfile).

Comment: Is the purpose of this to reduce IO time?

Comment: You misused `repr()`. `repr` is designed to provide a printable version of a object. It doesn't care about readability.

Comment: @Leonardo.Z The Python3 version does care about readability. So do I. Grepping that log for non-ASCII strings (think Japanese filenames) is not fun if all you see is a heap of \uABCD.

Comment: @user2357112 The purpose of this is to get log entries which are both human- and machine-readable. My code works, but it's butt-ugly IMHO (I never had to write _eight_ backslashes in a row, before this). Getting it to be faster would be a welcome side effect of doing this in a better way.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think Python 2 provides a way to do this, but it's easy to write your own code.

```
import unicodedata

def unichr_repr(ch):
    if ch == '\\':
        return '\\\\'
    elif ch == "'":
        return "\\'"
    category = unicodedata.category(ch)
    if category == 'Cc':
        if ch == '\n':
            return '\\n'
        n = ord(ch)
        if n < 0x100:
            return '\\x%02x' % n
        if n < 0x10000:
            return '\\u%04x' % n
        return '\\U%08x' % n
    return ch

def unistr_repr(s):
    return "'" + ''.join(unichr_repr(ch) for ch in s) + "'"
```

Comment: Speaking of Unicode categories, there's the regex module … which would speed up this solution substantially. As it is, it's much too slow.

Comment: See my answer - `Cc` is not enough

Answer (score 0):

Here's a more complete solution, that works for lists of unicode strings as well:

```
import reprlib
import sys

class URepr(reprlib.Repr):
    """
    On python 3, repr returns unicode objects, which means that non-ASCII
    characters are rendered in human readable form.

    This provides a similar facility on python 2.

    Additionally, on python 3, it prefixes unicode repr with a u, such that
    the returned repr is a valid unicode literal on both python 2 and python
    3
    """

    # From https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/3.6/Objects/unicodectype.c#L147-L1599
    nonprintable_categories = ('Cc', 'Cf', 'Cs', 'Co', 'Cn', 'Zl', 'Zp', 'Zs')

    if sys.version_info.major >= 3:
        def repr_str(self, obj, level):
            return 'u' + super().repr_str(obj, level)
    else:
        def repr_unicode(self, obj, level):
            def _escape(ch):
                # printable characters that have special meanings in literals
                if ch == u'\\':
                    return u'\\\\'
                elif ch == u"'":
                    return u"\\'"

                # non-printable characters - convert to \x.., \u...., \U........
                category = unicodedata.category(ch)
                if category in self.nonprintable_categories:
                    return ch.encode('unicode-escape').decode('ascii')

                # everything else
                return ch

            return u"u'{}'".format(''.join(_escape(c) for c in obj))
```

Usable as:

```
repr = URepr().repr

repr([u'hello', u'world'])
```

Answer (score 0):

Whilst I understand that you wish to use your method if you are receiving Unicode as a numerical value may I suggest the function `chr()` instead?

Answer (score -1):

Try doing

```
repr(string).decode("utf-8")
```

Comment: ??? how would that help me? repr() in Python2 returns an ASCII string. decode("utf-8") is a no-op on ASCII.